# how to disable parameters loaded from yaml from being displayed in terminal?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you load parameters from YAML in a roslaunch file , they get displayed in terminal, since I am having lot of variables it is getting difficult to debug. Is there anyway to prevent them from being printed in terminal ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349820/how-to-disable-parameters-loaded-from-yaml-from-being-displayed-in-terminal-?/) by [abstracto](https://answers.ros.org/users/25868/abstracto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does adding `--no-summary` to your `roslaunch` invocation quiets things down sufficiently?

> When you load parameters from YAML in a roslaunch file , they get displayed in terminal

this behaviour is not specific to parameters from a `.yaml`. All parameters are printed to the console as part of the *Summary*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abstracto](https://answers.ros.org/users/25868/abstracto/) on 2020-04-20**:
Thank you so much, this helps a lot.